# How to use a custom field in a joomla component view template

Tags: php, xml, joomla

i have created a dropdown select list custom field as what is taught in joomla document, but i do not get the idea of calling this field in a component template.

the code suggested in the document is like this,

```
//Get custom field
JFormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/fields');
$cities = JFormHelper::loadFieldType('City', false);
$cityOptions=$cities->getOptions(); // works only if you set your field getOptions on public!!
```

but how can it show like a select form? like

```
<select>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
</select>
```

The field definition code is like this:

```
<?php
// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

// The class name must always be the same as the filename (in camel case)
class JFormFieldRank extends JFormField {

    //The field class must know its own type through the variable $type.
    protected $type = 'Rank';

    public function getLabel() {
            // code that returns HTML that will be shown as the label
    }

    public function getInput() {
            // code that returns HTML that will be shown as the form field
            return '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
                   '<option value="0" >00 President</option>'.
                   '<option value="1" >01 Vice President</option>'.
                   '<option value="10" >10 General Secretary</option>'.
                   '<option value="20" >20 Financial Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="21" >21 Financial Deputy Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="30" >30 Academics Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="31" >31 Academics Deputy Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="40" >40 Public Relation Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="41" >41 Public Relation Deputy Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="50" >50 Publicity Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="51" >51 Publicity Deputy Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="60" >60 Social and Sports Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="61" >61 Social and Sports Deputy Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="70" >70 Logistics and Welfare Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="71" >71 Logistics and Welfare Deputy Chair</option>'.
                   '<option value="80" >80 IPSSSCB Advisor</option>'.                       
                   '</select>';

    }
}
```

Second, the xml file in the forms folder, what should be its name? the same with the custom field name? which is *rank.xml*?

and in the xml file, like following: can i change the name, label, description tag?

```
<field name="title" type="Rank" label="JGLOBAL_TITLE"
    description="JFIELD_TITLE_DESC"
    required="true" />

<fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_committee/models/fields">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a totally normal list field to me, why are you defining it as a custom field?   That is say type="list" and then put your xml in the xml file just as for any list field (there are dozens of examples in the core forms).

```
<field name="title" type="list" label="COM_MYCOMPONENT_FIELD_TITLE_LABEL"
        description="COM_MYCOMPONNET_TITLE_DESC"
        required="true" >
        <option value="0" >00 President</option>
        <option value="1" >01 Vice President</option>
        <option value="10" >10 General Secretary</option>
        <option value="20" >20 Financial Chair</option>
        <option value="21" >21 Financial Deputy Chair</option>
        <option value="30" >30 Academics Chair</option>
         ...
        <option value="80" >80 IPSSSCB Advisor</option>
</field>
```

Of course you can change the text, that's the whole point of having those as string keys, you make your own keys in your component language file. Again look at any form field in a core form. Best practice would be to use language keys for the values also.

Comment: But, i want to use the field in a site template, how can i call the field in the xml?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a site template"? This isn't a template parameter, which would be something about the template like "background color," it looks to be something about some individuals.  You don't want that field on every single page of your website do you?
If you have made your own component, do you have an MVC triad for the form view?

Comment: sorry, i built a component, and in a view default.php, there is a form, in the form i want a input box named 'rank' using the custom field.

Comment: Yes?  Your component has a model to move the data to the database and a view to render the form and a controller to manage the whole thing right?   So in your layout just like in all the other forms you would do something like     <div class="control-label">
     <?php echo $displayData->getForm()->getLabel('rank'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
     <?php echo $displayData->getForm()->getInput('rank'); ?>
    </div>

Comment: last question, i want to set the input field with the name 'rank', which is with the same name of the database field, so that i can insert data of the form through 'post' method to database, so where should i set the field name? in the xml file?

Comment: how should i change the name, label, description tag?

Comment: i encounter an error, calling getForm() on a non-object, can you give me the full code, please?

Comment: Me pasting code when I know nothing about your component is not going to help you. You need to debug your code and figure out why it's not an object and how you should change it.  Anyway that code is just from core joomla with the field name changed, you can see and study dozens of examples of forms in core Joomla.

Comment: hey, can you see my another question: *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619157/calling-a-custom-filed-with-error-of-calling-getform-of-non-object*  thank you